# Combining Distinct and TOP 1 in Union | SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have this following SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT (employeeidno, 4)deptcode 
from employeemasterfile 
ORDER BY deptcode ASC
```

yields a `DISTINCT` value of `D001` to `D051`

```
SELECT TOP 1 RIGHT (employeeidno, 7) empno 
from employeemasterfile  
ORDER BY empno DESC
```

yields a value of `0000267`

What I'm trying to achieve here is that every `DISTINCT` value of `D001` to `D051` should yield its `TOP 1` value.

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
deptcode :D001; empno: 0000016

deptcode :D002; empno: 0000024

deptcode :D004; empno: 0000029

deptcode :D005; empno: 0000020

deptcode :D006; empno: 0000056

deptcode :D007; empno: 0000164
```

> deptcode will display all the unique D001-D007, and empno will display the TOP1 for every unique deptcode.

```
select deptcode, empno 
from
(
SELECT TOP 1 RIGHT (employeeidno, 7) empno from employeemasterfile  ORDER BY empno DESC
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT (employeeidno, 4)deptcode from employeemasterfile ORDER BY deptcode ASC
) results
ORDER BY deptcode
```

Unfortunately I can't do it because if I'm going to add a new parameter, UNION won't work.

May I ask for your assistance on this concern?

A sample data looks like this

```
D0010000001
D0010000002
D0010000003
D0010000004
D0010000005
D0010000006
D0010000007
D0010000008
D0010000009
D0010000010
D0010000011
D0010000012
D0010000013
D0010000014
D0010000015
D0010000016
D0020000001
D0020000002
D0020000003
D0020000004
D0020000005
D0020000006
D0020000007
D0020000008
D0020000009
D0020000010
D0020000011
D0020000012
D0020000013
D0020000014
D0020000015
D0020000016
D0020000017
D0020000018
D0020000019
```

and so on until D0520000001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `GROUP BY LEFT(employeeidno, 4)`:

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(employeeidno, 4) deptcode,
  MAX(RIGHT(employeeidno, 7)) empno
FROM employeemasterfile
GROUP BY LEFT(employeeidno, 4)
ORDER BY LEFT(employeeidno, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, if you don't mind, can you please explain this sql query as simple as possible, I understand some of it, example, I don't understand how MAX() can sort everything out since the query will load it one by one.

Comment: `GROUP BY LEFT(employeeidno, 4)` returns distinct values of `LEFT(employeeidno, 4)` and for each of them the maximum value of `RIGHT(employeeidno, 7)`. This maximum value you get when sorting descending and get the top 1.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's clear now. Apologies, I double clicked the check button.

Answer (score 2):

you could use row_number()

```
select deptcode,empno from
 ( select LEFT (employeeidno, 4) deptcode,
          RIGHT (employeeidno, 7) empno,
  row_number()over(partition by LEFT (employeeidno, 4) ordere by RIGHT (employeeidno, 7) desc)
 from employeemasterfile
) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it aggregation should do it.

```
SELECT left(employeeidno, 4) deptcode,
       max(right(employeeidno, 7)) empno
       FROM employeemasterfile
       GROUP BY left(employeeidno, 4)
       ORDER BY left(employeeidno, 4);
```

---

Edit:

I'll try and explain it:

You can imagine `GROUP BY left(employeeidno, 4)` partitions the set of records into subsets. In each of that subsets the `left(employeeidno, 4)`, i.e. the `deptno` is the same and there are no two subsets with the same `deptno`. Now in each of the subsets `max(right(employeeidno, 7))` takes the maximum `right(employeeidno, 7)` i.e. the maximum `empno`. (Doing an `ORDER BY empno DESC` limiting the result to one row with `TOP 1` is also getting you the maximum.) The end result is then produced by taking the `deptno` of each of the subsets (i.e. each `deptno` once) and the maximum `empno`.

Comment: Thank you for this, if you don't mind, can you please explain this sql query as simple as possible, I understand some of it, example, I don't understand how MAX() can sort everything out since the query will load it one by one.

Comment: Thank you! I don't usually use MAX(), but I think I get it now, this is better than trying to do it via ````UNION````. Thanks for this.